# How do you find the convergence range of this series?

Tags: calculus

[Image of formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CY6c.jpg)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1n\tan\left(\frac 1n\right)x^n$$

Since $\frac{1}{n}\tan(\frac{1}{n})\rightarrow 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity, I am not sure how to get the limit of $a(n+1)/an.$

Comment: Are you able to find a lower bound for $a_n$ ? This could help

Answer (score 2):

If $x=1$ it converges since the general terms is equivalent to $\frac1{n^2}$. If $x>1$ then the general term is equivalent to $\frac{x^n}{n^2}$ which diverges, so the series diverges too.